# Trying to format an EditText to be a double with two decimal places using TextWatcher

Tags: android, infinite-loop, number-formatting, android-textwatcher

I am trying to automatically place a decimal two places in when the user begins to type in an `EditText`. The problem is I'm trying to set the `TextWatcher` on the `EditText` that I'm working with so when it updates the text in the field it recursively calls the method again. I'm getting an infinite loop. Here is what I've tried:

```
mTime.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                mTime.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                if(mTime.getText().length() > 2){
                    double amount = Double.valueOf(mTime.getText().toString());
                    amount /= 100.0;
                } 
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                mTime.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
```

mTime is the `EditText`'s name. My thinking was that once I triggered `onTextChanged`, I would remove the `TextChangedListener`, update the `EditText` and then re-instate the `TextChangedListener` in `afterTextChanged`. Unfortunately this didn't work. Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

This should be an easy task. I guess I'm just missing it

Answer (score 0):

you have pretty much right just make few changes below to your code:

```
 mTime.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                mTime.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                if(mTime.getText().length() > 2){
                    double amount = Double.valueOf(mTime.getText().toString());
                    amount /= 100.0;
                } 
                mTime.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
```